# Where to locate build.gradle file in android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, build.gradle

I found a tutorial to implement pull-to-refresh on android app and it says edit your build.gradle file and add the dependencies so it can use the android support library but I couldn't find the `build.gradle` file where can I find it? And I am using **Eclipse**.

Answer (score 5):

Google ends the eclipse supports, so it's time to move on Android Studio.

To add dependency in Project, first of all you need to convert eclipse project into the Android Studio project.

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html

After that you can find the build.gradle file in app folder of the project, there you can add dependency for any other supported library.

Comment: So i cant add dependencies unless i use android studio?

Comment: @ChiragRaval Your answer is right but your comment is not correct. To add dependencies you have to run a gradle command to sync the dependencies. Android Studio is not a requirement for this.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Thanks for the addressing, it really helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle is just a plugin you can add it in eclipse and build your project using it similar to android studio

you can refer [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html) tutorial to add gradle to your project

Note: It is recommended to use Android studio for android app development as it is google's official IDE for Android app development https://developer.android.com/studio/features.html

Answer (score 0):

Google officially declared some years ago that may not be introduced new feature.

Reference url please visit here to learn about android studio
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html